# List transform error in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml and I am trying to write a function to do this:

```
(4,a)(1,b)(2,c)(2,a)(1,d)(4,e) --> ((4 a) b (2 c) (2 a) d (4 e))
```

and this is what I wrote:

```
let rec transform l =
 match l with
 | (x,y)::t -> if x = 1 then y::transform(t) else [x; y]::transform(t)
 | [] -> []
```

I put it in the ocaml interpreter but error generated like this:

```
Error: This expression has type int list
   but an expression was expected of type int
```

Could anyone give some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example transformation doesn't make it clear what the types of the values are supposed to be.

If they're supposed to be lists, the result isn't a possible list in OCaml. OCaml lists are homogeneous, i.e., all the elements of the list have the same type. This is (in essence) what the compiler is complaining about.

**Update**

Looking at your code, the problem is here:

```
if x = 1
then y :: transform (t)
else [x; y] :: transform t
```

Let's say the type of y is `'a`. The expression after `then` seems to have type `'a list`, because y is the head of the list. The expression after `else` seems to have type `'a list list`, because a list containing y is the head of the list. These aren't the same type.

Comment: I think (4,a) should be tuple... but the result is a list consists of several sublists...

Comment: You should write your example in OCaml notation, it would be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is to decide how to represent something as either `(4 a)` or `b`. The usual OCaml way to represent something-or-something-else is variants, so let's define one of those:

```
type 'a element =
  | Single of 'a
  | Count of int * 'a

let rec transform = function
  | [] -> []
  | (x,y)::t ->
      if x = 1 then Single y::transform t
      else Count (x, y)::transform t
```

Note that this won't print in quite the way you want, unless you register a printer with the toplevel.

Or better:

```
let compact (x, y) =
  if x = 1 then Single y else Count (x, y)

let transform list = List.map compact list
```